# How can I know if a TLabel word wrapped the text?

Tags: delphi, word-wrap, tlabel

I create a `TLabel` and add text to it dynamically, and that works just fine. But I need to know if the label word-wrapped the text because it was too large for the label's width, or if there was no need to it to wrap because the text was shorter than the label's width.

I don't mean to know whether the label's `WordWrap` property is set to true or false, I want to know if it wrapped the text or it didn’t.

The `TLabel` has the `AutoSize` and `WordWrap` properties set to true, in case that matters.

Comment: The only way to do this is to manually calculate the text width the same way the `TLabel` does - using the Win32 [`DrawText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext) function (which is wrapped by the `TCanvas.TextRect()` overload that takes a `TTextFormat` as input).

Comment: Unless that label is Aligned the wrapping will not work because it is  **AutoSized** thus it will always change its size to fit the text in it

Comment: thanks for pointing that option Remy, I'll look into that and see how it goes and let you know.

Comment: yeah, you are right  Nasreddine, I made a mistake there. I am no longer setting the label to autoWidth.

Comment: Next time when you want to respond to someone use the '@' char followed by their name, Neither @Remy Nor I got notified of your comments. have a good weekend :).

Comment: thanks for the tip @NasreddineGalfout! I am still noob to the platform haha. much appreciated.

Comment: @NasreddineGalfout I didn’t get to try your answer, I'm sorry. I tried the code provided by Sertac and it worked as desired and it was pretty simple. is there any way I can Help you for answering? like voting you up or something?

Comment: haha I did not Answer, I meant that you should accept Sertac's answer. you made me smile thank you for that.

Comment: haha, I got it now. does that mean that I haven't accepted Sertac's answer yet? I think I did hahaha. could you confirm that @NasreddineGalfout?

Comment: yes you did, that green check confirms this :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check the label's height to find out if it is a one liner or not.

```
if Label1.Height = Label1.Canvas.TextHeight('.') then
  // no word wrapped
```

[That is because](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TLabel.AutoSize):

> When WordWrap is **True**, the width of the label is fixed. If AutoSize is
>   also **True**, changes to the text cause the label to change in height.

Comment: that sounds helpful, as im already going home from work I'll try your answer on Monday and I'll let you know how it goes. thanks!

Comment: Ok. If anyone doubts if height of a "." (or any single character) could be tested against the height of an arbitrary string, it could. GetTextExtentPoint32 does not differentiate height of characters.